# Speed up code (beautifulsoup, python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pretty new to python and beautifulsoup, I wrote this piece of code (attached only relevant part).
However it is very slow during execution, it takes around 8 seconds (I need to loop it few thousand times).

Could you give me any pointers how to make it faster ?
Every criticism welcomed.

PS. This may be relevant:
there are 20 rows on each page, columns 0..5 are short string up to 100 characters, 
the 6th column is bigger, it is a string up to 2000 characters,
requests.get(...) takes about 0.2 sec

```
    ReqHTMLContent = bs4.BeautifulSoup(ReqResult.text)


    ###############################################
    #print('Adding report ...', flush=True) 

    for TableRow in ReqHTMLContent.select('table#msgTable tr'):  
        #print (TableRow)

        RpName = TableRow.find_all('td')[0].get_text(strip=True)            
        RpArray[row][0] = RpName
        #print(RpName)

        RpCategory = TableRow.find_all('td')[1].get_text(strip=True)
        RpArray[row][1] = RpCategory
        #print(RpCategory)

        RpType = TableRow.find_all('td')[2].get_text(strip=True)
        RpArray[row][2] = RpType
        #print(RpType)

        RpTime = TableRow.find_all('td')[3].get_text(strip=True)
        RpArray[row][3] = RpTime
        #print(RpTime)

        RpTitle = TableRow.find_all('td')[4].get_text(strip=True)
        RpArray[row][4] = RpTitle
        #print(RpTitle)

        #linki i tresc raportu  
        for link in TableRow.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "evLK"}):
            RpLink = domain_url + link.get('href')  
            RpArray[row][5] = RpLink
            #print(RpLink) 

            #tresc raportu
            RpHtml = requests.get(RpLink)   
            RpRaw = bs4.BeautifulSoup(RpHtml.text)          

            #<div id="ctl00_Body_msgDetails1_eventReport" class="ItemA">     
            RpTable = RpRaw.find("div", attrs={"id": "ctl00_Body_msgDetails1_eventReport", "class": "ItemA"})                    
            RpText = RpTable.get_text("|", strip=True)
            RpArray[row][6]=RpText            
            #print(RpText)


        row += 1               
    ### for TableRow in ReqHTMLContent.select('table#msgTable tr'):
    ###############################################
```

Comment: If this code is working, just slowly, then you might be better off asking this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are calling `TableRow.find_all('td')` for each col. At each call soup will find 'td'. So put `TableRow.find_all('td')` in a variable and reuse variable to get values of each col.

Comment: The real problem lies in `requests.get()` for each link of each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using BS's `find_all` function several times, try to use it once and for all:

```
RpList = TableRow.find_all('td')

RpName = RpList[0].get_text(strip=True)
RpCategory = RpList[1].get_text(strip=True)
RpType = RpList[2].get_text(strip=True)
RpTime = RpList[3].get_text(strip=True)
RpTitle = RpList[4].get_text(strip=True)
```

This is not limited to that example. And as suggested, you could use a list comprehension to do that in fewer lines of code. But the cost of creating `RpName`, `RpType`... variables is nothing compared to the cost of calling BS functions. So if it helps to the clarity of your code, you can keep it.

Basically, this idea is to use BS a minimum, and Python a maximum.

Apart from that, I think the most costly part of your code is this line:

```
RpHtml = requests.get(RpLink)
```

Which is inside your nested loop. But if you need to access so many links because you need something that you can't find elsewhere, I can't see how you're gonna cut it.

Try to determine how many times this line is executed, since you say it takes approximatively 0.2 seconds. If it's called, let's say, 40 times, then you have your answer.

Do this if you want to test the net cost of `requests.get()` calls:

```
from time import time
start = time()
calls = 0
for link in TableRow.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "evLK"}):
    RpLink = domain_url + link.get('href')  
    RpArray[row][5] = RpLink
    calls += 1
print "get() was called %d times and took %d seconds"%(calls,time()-start)
```

Comment: This solution saved me 1sec from 8, I am going to check others

Comment: @klubow I think you won't manage to go under 6 or 7 seconds if you must call `requests.get()` for each link in each row. Isn't there any other place where you could find the same information in one shot? Or do you absolutely need this information?

Comment: I am trying to get it directly from webpage admin, I hope it goes well. Anyway, at later stage I will have to update my database with new records so I will have to use this code. The problem may be in requests for each loop it is called 20 times x 0,2 = 4sec

Answer (score 3):

Aside from other suggestions, use [`SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to parse only a part of the document.

Here's the modified code with other minor fixes:

```
from bs4 import SoupStrainer, BeautifulSoup
import requests

# we'll use "div" strainer later
div = SoupStrainer("div", attrs={"id": "ctl00_Body_msgDetails1_eventReport", "class": "ItemA"})

rows = SoupStrainer("table", id="msgTable")
soup = BeautifulSoup(ReqResult.content, parse_only=rows)

results = []
for row in soup.select('table#msgTable tr'):
    cells = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.find_all('td')]

    for link in row.select("a.evLK"):
        url = domain_url + link.get('href')
        cells.append(url)

        inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, parse_only=div)

        table = inner_soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "ctl00_Body_msgDetails1_eventReport", "class": "ItemA"})
        cells.append(table.get_text("|", strip=True))

    results.append(cells)
```

As a side note, and as others already mentioned, the key problem is in following the links in the loop. Since this is a synchronous operation, it is blocking the program execution and makes it slow - you cannot follow the next link until you are done with a previous one. Switching to an **asynchronous** approach can dramatically improve the performance. Here are few options:

- [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) (a web-scraping framework based on twisted)
- [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (requests+gevent)

Comment: Using threading could make a asynchronous approach too.

Comment: `SoupStrainer` really sped my finds up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could change this:

```
RpName = TableRow.find_all('td')[0].get_text(strip=True)            
RpArray[row][0] = RpName
#print(RpName)

RpCategory = TableRow.find_all('td')[1].get_text(strip=True)
RpArray[row][1] = RpCategory
#print(RpCategory)

RpType = TableRow.find_all('td')[2].get_text(strip=True)
RpArray[row][2] = RpType
#print(RpType)

RpTime = TableRow.find_all('td')[3].get_text(strip=True)
RpArray[row][3] = RpTime
#print(RpTime)

RpTitle = TableRow.find_all('td')[4].get_text(strip=True)
RpArray[row][4] = RpTitle
#print(RpTitle)
```

To this:

```
RpArray[row] = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in TableRow.find_all('td')]
```

And if you want to use one of the values, you can do this:

```
RpName = RpArray[row][0]
```

Comment: Thank you all especially Jivan, the main problem is in request.get which takes 4sec out of 8sec of total time.

Answer (score 1):

Joining both answer from Vincent Beltman and Jivan:

```
RpList = TableRow.find_all('td')
RpArray[row] = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in RpList]
```

Find all 'td' just once, and loop over with a single expression.